# BasicDBObject in MongoDB refusing to take value integer

Tags: java, mongodb

I cannot add the value 30 to key age i am getting error that says: The method `put(String, Object)` in the type `BasicBSONObject` is not applicable for the arguments `(String, int)`. also for `newDate` method

```
  BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
  document.put("name", "baja");
  document.put("age", 30);
  document.put("createdDate", newDate());
  table.insert(document);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static MongoDatabase db;
private static final String collectionName = "tweets";


final MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(DB_URL); 
//example mongodb://localhost:27017/databaseName 

final MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
db = client.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());

 Document document = new Document();
 document.put("name", "baja");
 document.put("age", 30);
 document.put("createdDate",new Date());
 db.getCollection(collectionName).insertOne(document);
```